# Voice over is not reading what I am typing in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, electron, voiceover

Below is my code:

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group loginFormGrp">
            <label class="caption">Backup Cloud</label>
            <div class="custSelect loginSelect">
            <label class="caption">Server URL</label>
                <input type="text" aria-label="Server URL" name="serverUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="example.server.com" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group loginFormGrp">
                <label class="caption">Email</label>
                <input type="text" aria-label="Email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="user@example.com" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="loginBtnRow">
                <button tabindex="0" type="submit" class="lgBtn btn btn-primary btn-block">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

whenever voiceover highlights the input text field it reads "You are currently on text field, inside web content. To enter text in this filed, type. To exit web area,.."
and when I Start typing it says nothing.
and checked other appilcation or websites it reads what i am typing.
but in my case its not reading.
Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: What browsers are you using? Also does the HTML change when rendered? Is there any validations happening on fields (like jQuery Validation)? Using plain html you provider it works in latest Safari and Chrome. Firefox does not, but it seems to be a Firefox issue.

Comment: As you mentioned it is an electron APP can i know the operating system you getting this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Add `title` attribute to the input element and provide additional text.

Adding `aria-label` to the input elements should also be picked by the screen readers.

http://pauljadam.com/demos/title-aria-label.html provides details on how different browsers and screen readers treat these attributes.

Comment: tried with title attribute but not working.
Also tried removing aria-label. not working
my application is inside Electron

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems pretty fine. I tried with a chrome plugin called ChromeVox everything seems to be fine except that add the lang attribute to the parent html tag and enclose everything in a body tag some thing like this.

```
<html lang="en-US" style="height: 100%;">
<body>
 <form>
        <div class="form-group loginFormGrp">
            <label class="caption">Backup Cloud</label>
            <div class="custSelect loginSelect">
            <label class="caption">Server URL</label>
                <input type="text" aria-label="Server URL" name="serverUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="example.server.com" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group loginFormGrp">
                <label class="caption">Email</label>
                <input type="text" aria-label="Email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="user@example.com" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="loginBtnRow">
                <button tabindex="0" type="submit" class="lgBtn btn btn-primary btn-block">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this'll help, but You may try to update fields `value` attribute, every time user modify text field. Something like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function(v){
    v.addEventListener('input', function(){
        v.setAttribute('value', v.value);
    });
});
```

But I wish someone provide better answer, without using extra JavaScript.